# Checkbox in Conditional Panel Shiny app doesn't display

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny

I am trying to build an app from an excel with multiple sheets. It works fine but the check boxes aren't displaying even though it actually affects the output. I know it affects the output because when I eliminate the selected option of the checkboxGroupInput no row is displayed, otherwise it is as expected. Maybe someone can tell me why the checkbox isn't displayed on the sidebar as expected. Thanks in advance.

> ```
>  require('shiny')
>  library(readxl)
>  read_excel_allsheets <- function(filename) {
>   sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(filename)
>  x <-   lapply(sheets, function(X) readxl::read_excel(filename, sheet = X,  
>   range =  cell_rows(c(6, NA))))
>  names(x) <- sheets
>   x
>   }
>  data <- read_excel_allsheets("data path")
>  ui <- fluidPage(
>   title = "Examples of DataTables",
>   sidebarLayout(
>     sidebarPanel(
>       conditionalPanel(
>        'input.dataset === "CUB 9"',
>         checkboxGroupInput("show_vars", "Companies:",
>                         unique(data$'CUB 9'$Company), 
>                         selected = unique(data$'CUB 9'$Company))
>    ),
>    conditionalPanel(
>     'input.dataset === "CUP 14"',
>      checkboxGroupInput("show_vars1", "Companies: in CUP 14",
>                       unique(data$'CUP  14'$Company), 
>                       selected = unique(data$'CUP  14'$Company))
>   )
>  ),
>  mainPanel(
>   tabsetPanel(
>     id = 'dataset',
>     tabPanel("data$'CUB 9'", dataTableOutput("mytable1")),
>     tabPanel("data$'CUP  14'", dataTableOutput("mytable2"))
>     )
>    )
>   )
>  )
>
> server <- 
>         function(input, output) {
>           output$mytable1 <- renderDataTable({data$'CUB 9'[which(data$'CUB 
>           9'$Company %in% c(input$show_vars)),]
>            })
>         output$mytable2 <- renderDataTable({data$'CUP  14'[which(data$'CUP  
>          14'$Company %in% c(input$show_vars1)),] 
>           })
>   }
>  shinyApp(ui, server)
> ```

Comment: Are you sure these conditions are getting satisfied?  ```'input.dataset === "CUB 9"',```

Comment: Your conditional panels depend of an input which is never incremented. You should have something such as a `selectInput` to make `input.dataset ` depending on that inputs. Further, sometimes you have `CUB  14` with two blank spaces, and sometimes there is just one : it may give you some errors.

Comment: @amrrs, I would expect that if the condition isn't satisfied I should get some form of error or there won't be any output since the output is based on the same data.

Comment: @Smich7, I am not sure I totally understand what you mean.

Comment: Your condition depends on something which doesn't exist yet. You don't affect anything to `input.dataset` through the application. Add something like `selectInput('dataset',label='Check CUB',choices=c('CUB 9','CUB 14')`. In such a way the conditional panels depending on the `input.dataset` will be displays according to the value attributed to this latter.

Comment: @Smich7 No, `input.dataset` corresponds to the title of the active tab. The problem is that they are not named `CUB 9` and `CUB 14`.

Comment: @KH_ So change `tabPanel("data$'CUB 9'"...` to `tabPanel("CUB 9", ....`, etc, and this will work.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent, thanks a lot for pointing that out. It works fine now.